# Ajax - как сохранить результат в переменную?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

подскажите пожалуйста, как сохранить результат Ajax (rowid) в класс?

Например:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>product",
  method: "POST",
  data: {rowid:rowid},
  success:function(data) {   
    $(rowid).html(data);
  }
});
```

Если в таком виде, то получается : `$(test).html(data);` -- > а хочу получить `$('.test').html(data);`

спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let rowid = 'test';

$(`.${rowid}`).html(data); // $(`#${rowid}`).html(data);
```

А можно и сразу написать, не вижу преград

```
let rowid = '.test';

$(rowid).html(data);
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! просто rowid  это не константа и она меняется, в зависимости от полученного результата , хочу подставлять её в класс

Comment: @Kirill если не константа - то скорее всего что-то сделано не так в вёрстке. Как правило множество разных классов или идентификаторов с меняющейся цифрой на конце говорит об этом....... Но если прям надо - то первый вариант ответа для вас

Comment: Спасибо большое , ВАМ! То что нужно)